# How do you insert custom dynamic values to subtitle?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to insert current date to subtitle in highcharts as below:

```
   subtitle: {
     text: function() {
       var d = new Date();
       return '<b>' +  d + '</b>';
     },
   },
```

I am not getting Date value instead I am getting the function printed as the subtitle. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d.toDateString(); or d.toLocaleDateString(); or d.toString(); ...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate

Comment: actually it did work, I had to declare and assing d globally.

Answer (score 0):

In case when you use function, you need to call by autorun function (closure):

```
 text: (function () {
            return 'aaaaa dynamic'
        })(),
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kem7d/